# Show the entry category, that´s it

Tags: templating, categories

I have a simple and maybe a stupid question, it´s my first Craft Website...

I´m listing  a news section, the news can be categorized ( max two categories ), and i don´t know how to show the category name in the news list items, the category field name is "**categoriaNot**"

```
{% for blog in craft.entries.section('noticias').limit(10) %}

    <!--inicia noticia-->
    <div class="item noticiaItem">
        <div class="noticiaImg">
            {% set imagen = blog.imagenNot.first() %}

            {% if imagen %}
                <a href="{{ blog.url }}" title="{{ blog.title }}"><img src="{{ imagen.getUrl('thumb') }}"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/></a>
            {% endif %} 
        </div> 
        <div class="noticiaTxtWrap">
            <span class="catNoticia">
                **** CATEGORY NAME HERE ****
            </span>

            <a class="tituloNoticia" href="{{ blog.url }}"> {{ blog.title }}</a>

            <span class="dateNoticia"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Publicado el: {{ blog.postDate.format('d.m.Y') }}</span>

            <span class="resumenNoticia">
                {{ blog.resumenNot }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--finaliza noticia-->

{% endfor %}
```

Any help will be welcome!

thanks!

Sebastián.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, it should be as simple as this:

```
<span class="catNoticia">
    {% if blog.myCategoryFieldHandle|length %}
        <ul>
            {% for category in blog.myCategoryFieldHandle %}
                <li>{{ category.title }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</span>
```